# How to create multiple subsets of DataFrame with loop

Tags: python, pandas

## Base DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100,6)),columns = 
['red','blue','yellow','green','purple','total'])
```

## How do I code this with a loop?

```
df_x = df[df.columns[[y,5]]]
```

I'd like to apply this logic to a dataframe with many more columns, but for simplicity sake, boiled down the question into this.

Below is desired output, 5 new dataframes created (Assuming I don't have to type all the 5 lines)

```
df_red = df[df.columns[[0,5]]]
df_blue = df[df.columns[[1,5]]]
df_yellow = df[df.columns[[2,5]]]
df_green = df[df.columns[[3,5]]]
df_purple = df[df.columns[[4,5]]]
```

Comment: Why is it that you are wanting to do this? It is possible or even likely splitting them into separate DataFrames isn't really necessary.

Comment: I agree, it's not very likely, but I could think of scenarios where it might be needed.

Comment: Such as? Now I'm curious :)

Comment: It's more for my learning purpose actually more than anything. I was talking about a scenario where you might need to create say 100 dataframes based on the base table and need convert it to csv and send it out to 100 different receiver who will need to do an analysis or print it out as hard copy, again it's unlikely, but I wanted to see if there's a way to do such a task programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `groupby` `axis =1` and `pd.concat`

```
variables = locals()
for x , y  in df.iloc[:,:-1].groupby(level=0,axis=1):
    variables["df_{0}".format(x)] =pd.concat([y,df.iloc[:,[-1]]],axis=1)


df_red.head()

Out[566]: 
   red  total
0    4      7
1    7      9
2    6      7
3    4      2
4    5      8
```

Comment: "df red head"... nice!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ haha, it is too long to print all :-)

Comment: @Wen Thank you so much! Worked out seamlessly, idk why the operation that seems so simple won't come out from my head haha. Def need alot of practice